# Which Ubuntu version to use on a MAXDATA laptop Eco 3100X ? with this system info

Tags: drivers, vga, version, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu on 256MB RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47461/ubuntu-on-256mb-ram)

i am speaking as new ubuntu user, i just have installed ubuntu 10.04 on my laptop, but is running very slow...

So i am here to ask you a question: WHich ubuntu version can fit for my laptop MAXDATA Eco 3100x, .

And the screen freezes sometimes, i did install the lubuntu and xubuntu extention, still problem.. MAybe is a the video driver not configured as it should, i had the same issue with windows xp, but i installed the vga video drivers of it then it was ok. But on Ubuntu this driver i could not installed, what to do?

My Laptop System Information are:

```
SYSTEM INFORMATION
    Running Ubuntu Linux, the Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) release.
    GNOME: 2.30.2 (Ubuntu 2010-06-25)
    Kernel version: 2.6.32-40-generic (#87-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 5 20:26:31 UTC 2012)
    GCC: 4.4.3 (i486-linux-gnu)
    Xorg: unknown (25 February 2012  06:59:39AM) (25 February 2012  06:59:39AM)
    Hostname: lotus-laptop
    Uptime: 0 days 1 h 6 min

CPU INFORMATION
    GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz
    Number of CPUs: 1
    CPU clock currently at 2390.561 MHz with 512 KB cache
    Numbering: family(15) model(2) stepping(7)
    Bogomips: 4781.12
    Flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe up pebs bts cid

MEMORY INFORMATION
    Total memory: 228 MB
    Total swap: 455 MB

STORAGE INFORMATION
    SCSI device -  scsi0
        Vendor:  ATA     
        Model:  IBM-DJSA-210    
    SCSI device -  scsi1
        Vendor:  TOSHIBA 
        Model:  DVD-ROM SD-C2502

HARDWARE INFORMATION
MOTHERBOARD
    Host bridge
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 650/M650 Host (rev 11)
    PCI bridge(s)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge (AGP)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge (AGP)
    USB controller(s)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller (prog-if 20)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10)
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller (prog-if 20)
    ISA bridge
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS962 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 04)
    IDE interface
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 [IDE] (prog-if 80 [Master])
        Subsystem: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 [IDE]

GRAPHIC CARD
    VGA controller
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 65x/M650/740 PCI/AGP VGA Display Adapter
        Subsystem: Uniwill Computer Corp Device 5103

SOUND CARD
    Multimedia controller
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AC'97 Sound Controller (rev a0)
        Subsystem: Uniwill Computer Corp Device 5203

NETWORK
    Ethernet controller
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS900 PCI Fast Ethernet (rev 91)
        Subsystem: Uniwill Computer Corp Device 5002
    Modem
        Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AC'97 Modem Controller (rev a0)
        Subsystem: Uniwill Computer Corp Device 4003
```

Thanks you asap.
:-)
E

Comment: 228MB... on a P4? What happened to the other RAM?

Comment: @Lekensteyn - It is using a Sis video card. From the 256MB RAM it is taking a part for the video and maybe other integrated cards. And yes this is a duplicate of that question which in turn is a duplicate of another 2 questions.

Answer (score -1):

If Ubuntu is slow then you probably need to change your settings.  Right click somewhere on the desktop and select "Background."  Next click the "Visual Setting Tab" and check "None."  If you need games and applications which run on a slower machine then I would recommend dotdeb.com, those games work great on my laptop and are some of the least resource intensive I've seen.

Comment: ever time i open some windows the pc slows to much.. maybe the video drivers are not the right one ?

Comment: Look i have tryed all the mentioned options steel the image freezes , so this is not the solutions of closing the case.. pleas proved some info how to fix the vga drivers for the laptop?