# How to install Ubuntu onto a 2GB flash drive?

Tags: usb, system-installation

I have a development board with Intel Atom processor, ICH8M chipset, 1GB RAM, 2GB flash memory. So basically it's a Netbook configuration already, but without hard drive.

Is possible to install Ubuntu into the on board 2GB flash memory using a USB drive?

Comment: I think the standard Ubuntu distro is larger than 2G. I would go find a smaller distro.

Comment: it can be done but i would try 7.4 or 7.10 for 2g if you have 4g that you can install 9.10 or
10.4

Answer (score 3):

Try the Mini ISO image. Click [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) to download it (for Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit).

For more information take a look at this question:

- [How can I reduce the Ubuntu install size to the minimum, with GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46175/how-can-i-reduce-ubuntu-install-size-to-the-minimum-with-gui)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried in a couple of years, but there used to be the option to use Live CD version on a USB with a persistent file.

Here, you would have 700MB plus perhaps a 1024 MB persisient file.  It would bnot be a normal install, but could work (or at least used to in the past).

Someone with better insight will likely correct me here.

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/  shows how to set up with a persistent file.  It will be slower to use than with a full install, but you cannot do a full install on a 2 Gig stick anyway.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is difficult to help you without knowing which board it is.

Try to setup ubuntu on your flash disk (it is easy using the start media creator from the system menu on your ubuntu host computer) and then boot the board from this flash drive and after that install ubuntu on the flash memory (which might be identified as a hard drive)

Comment: Thanks for your update. The board info can be found [here](http://www.advantech.com/products/SOM-7562-B1/mod_BE595CF3-DD13-4C65-BF74-65EEA04745E9.aspx). as i mentioned, basically a typical Netbook configuration without hard drive. However, standard Ubuntu will ask for a minimal hard disk space (4.4GB?) in order to install right? anyway to bypass that?